# Harvest a THREDDS server correctly with GeoNetwork?

Tags: netcdf, geonetwork, thredds

I am trying to harvest datasets (NetCDF) from a THREDDS server using GeoNetwork 2.10.

People shall upload their NetCDF files to the THREDDS server and the CatalogScan element will list them. After the harvest task was run, new metadata harvested from the THREDDS catalog will be displayed on the GeoNetwork page.

By now, I do get data returned from harvesting. My problem is that the data is not displayed correctly and many items are missing. I've followed instructions from [the GeoNetwork THREDDS harvesting](https://www.geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/users/managing_metadata/harvesting/thredds/index.html#thredds-harvester) tutorial.

The data returned looks like this:

[image: data returned]

As you can see there are many fields missing. The catalog.xml is configured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog name="KüNO NetCDF TDS"
     xmlns="http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/thredds/InvCatalog/v1.0"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <service name="all" base="" serviceType="compound">
        <service name="ncdods" serviceType="OpenDAP" base="/thredds/dodsC/"/>
        <service name="HTTPServer" serviceType="HTTPServer" base="/thredds/fileServer/"/>
        <service name="ncss" serviceType="NetcdfSubset" base="/thredds/ncss/grid/"/>
    </service>
    <datasetScan name="NetCDF Katalog" ID="netcdf_katalog" path="katalog" location="content/katalog" harvest="true">
        <metadata inherited="true">
        <serviceName>ncdods</serviceName>
        <dataType>Grid</dataType>
        <filter>
            <include wildcard="*.nc"/>
        </filter>
        <netcdf xmlns="http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/namespaces/netcdf/ncml-2.2">
            <attribute name="Conventions" value="CF-1.0"/>
        </netcdf>
        </metadata>
    </datasetScan>
</catalog>
```

And the GeoNetwork harvester is setup like this:

[image: GeoNetwork harvester]

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?